# Not all mail received by customers when changing the order status in Prestashop

Tags: php, email, prestashop, alert

I've got a strange issue with Prestashop 1.6.1.3. I'll try to be clear.
I have the "mail alerts" module installed and updated (v 3.6.1).

I have configured in my back office that when some order status change, it will send a mail to the customer. As you can see in the image below, when the order is payed, in preparation or shipped, the customer normally have to receive an email.
[image: Back-office -> Orders -> status]
The customer never receive these emails. But when i try to send an email test, or when i respond to a customer question or even when a customer register, email works! So i can say it's working but not for these steps of changing status.

To be more precise, when i go to an order detail, and then i try to manually re-send the mail it's not working too. Prestashop tells me the mail is sent but nothing is received.

On the image below you can see in red emails that are not working when i re-send it and in green emails that actually work. As you see when i re-send email for canceled order, the customer receive it.
[image: Back-office -> Orders -> Order detail]
I can also precise that email are logged in Prestashop log, i've got no error in log for these emails.

Yesterday i tried to send 11 emails by changing status of an order or by clicking on the resend mail button, nothing was in the customer mail. These emails were logged by Prestashop (still with no error) AND when i go to see my admin page at OVH i can see these emails were sent too and without error!
[image: OVH]
Finally i can tell that i use mail function of php in my settings in Prestashop, but i have also tried with SMTP and it was the exactly the same...
Now, i don't know where i can investigate... Right now i'm looking inside AdminOrderController.php but i can't find....

Hope someone can help me or give a clue.
Thanks in advance for your future answer.

Comment: Have you checked if all different templates have all available languages? For example, if order-confirmation doesn't have one particular language and it tries to send that template in that language, it could fail.

Comment: Yes, i haven't precise it but all email templates are here in "en" and "fr" directory

Answer (score 0):

What kind of mailer are you using in the Prestashop Advanced settings?
In the past I used PHPmailer() but I had similar issues.

Did you configure mails via SMTP ?

Comment: As i wrote in the description, "but i have also tried with SMTP and it was the exactly the same... "

Comment: Hi Siick. I was thinking about your problem. I had a similar issue myself with my custom module to send product keys. I discovered then, that one of the mail templates was missing. See /mails folder.

Have you tried all of the types of mails? Can you check if item is out of stock also? Or what if a customer registers himself? You can check all the templates. Maybe the mail template is missing for the customer language. I hope I can help you with this.

PS: If you use SMTP mailing, at least you can check the mails in your mailbox. So stick to that anyway !

Comment: For sure, it's not a template problem.  
All email templates are here in "en" and "fr" directory.